# combining data part with header part

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to combine a a file which has the header and another file which has the data component. For example…

`header.bcp` (all on one line, not restricted to 4 columns):

```
SNO,Name,Age,Gender ......
```

`data.bcp` (multiple lines with the number of fields same as columns):

```
1,"ABC",20,"M" .....
2,"XYZ",22,"F" .....
```

The expected output should be:

```
SNO=1,Name="ABC",Age=20,Gender="M" ....
SNO=2,Name="XYZ",Age=22,Gender="F" ....
```

My guess was with `awk`, any quick solutions, thoughts ?

Answer (score 2):

Quick 'n' dirty solution *if the fields cannot include embedded commas* as mentioned in the comments:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=FS} 
  NR==FNR {split($0,a); next} 
  {
    for(i=1; i<=NF;i++) $i=a[i]"="$i;
  } 1
' header.bcp data.bcp
```

Comment: @xhienne no sorry - overthinking it I guess. Please see edited version.

Comment: @xhienne ah that's good to know - so if the third argument is empty, it uses the current FS rather than the default FS I guess?

Comment: Exactly, and this is even POSIX-compliant